# Multiple TcpListeners not working

Tags: c#

I made an "Acceptor" class which in the cunstroctor it accepts an amount of TcpListeners. Starting from port 8484 and above.

```
  class Acceptor
{
    private List<TcpListener> Listeners;
    private static int clientCount = 0;
    private static int portStart = 8484;

    public Acceptor(int capacity)
    {
        Listeners = new List<TcpListener>(capacity);
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            Listeners.Add(new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, portStart));
            portStart++;
        }

        foreach (TcpListener listener in Listeners)
        {
            try
            {
                listener.Start();
                listener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), null);
            }
            catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to start TcpListener, Error {0}.", ex.Message);
            }
        }

        Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Initiated {0} Listeners from 8484 - {1}.", capacity, portStart));
    }

    public void EndAccept(IAsyncResult IAR)
    {
        TcpListener Listener = (TcpListener)IAR.AsyncState;
        Socket socket = Listener.EndAcceptSocket(IAR);
        frmMain.Clients.Add(clientCount, new Client(socket));
        Listener.Stop();
        Listener = null;
        clientCount++;

        frmMain.Instance.UpdateClients();  
    }
}
```

However, that doesn't work. The program crashes when accepting a new connection, why's that?

Comment: EDIT: This is the error I'm receving: http://puu.sh/4t1NM.jpg I know it's because I have to pass the listener after the async result.. but how?

Comment: Why create a list of them? you could handle them with 1 iterator?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen I wasn't sure how to do that, so I created a List, why not.

Comment: I think this solution goes wrong when you create another instance. You're altering the _private static int portStart = 8484;_ while it's static.... You should create a local copy of the _portStart_

Comment: For hint, you can accept multiple clients on the same listener. Just call BeginAccept again on the listener socket after EndAccept.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Just call the same line                 listener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), null); in EndAccept?

Comment: I'll post an example below, how i would do it. Test it with multiple telnet clients.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing null as the "state" in BeginAcceptSocket, thus the error when you attempt to cast it back and then use it.

Try changing this line:

```
listener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), null);
```

To:

```
listener.BeginAcceptSocket(new AsyncCallback(EndAccept), listener);
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after I went through the code. Same error still. I believe that's because of the multiple listeners.. is there an issuew ith my code?

Answer (score 0):

This is how i implement a Listener:

```
public class EasySocketListener : IDisposable
{
    private Socket _socket;

    public void Start(int port)
    {
        _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
        _socket.Listen(1);

        StartAccepting();
    }

    private void StartAccepting()
    {
        try
        {
            _socket.BeginAccept((asyncResult) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Socket clientSocket = _socket.EndAccept(asyncResult);
                    if (OnSocketAccept != null)
                        OnSocketAccept(this, new SocketEventArgs(clientSocket));

                    StartAccepting();
                }
                catch { }
            }, null);
        }
        catch { }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_socket != null)
        {
            _socket.Dispose();
            _socket = null;
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler<SocketEventArgs> OnSocketAccept;
}
```

This can accept multiple client sockets. When a client connects, the OnSocketAccept triggers.

Needs the SocketEventArgs:

```
public class SocketEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public Socket Socket { get; private set; }

    public SocketEventArgs(Socket socket)
    {
        Socket = socket;
    }
}
```

example:

```
private void Init()
{
    _listener = new EasySocketListener();
    _listener.OnSocketAccept += Listener_OnSocketAccept;
    _listener.Start(port);
}

private void Listener_OnSocketAccept(object sender, SocketEventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine( e.Socket.RemoteEndPoint );
}
```

This will come on my blog http://csharp.vanlangen.biz but haven't wrote it there yet. You can find some methods for reading asynchronous from a socket.